# Reading data from .txt file into Matlab

Tags: matlab, pari

I have been trying in vain for days to do one seemingly simple thing--I want to read data from a .txt file that looks like this:

```
    0.221351321
    0.151351321
    0.235165165
    8.2254546 E-7
```

into Matlab. I've been able to load the data in the .txt file as a column vector using the fscanf command, like so:

```
    U=fscanf(FileID, '%e')
```

provided that I go through the file first and remove the space before the 'E' wherever scientific notation occurs in the data set.

Since I have to generate a large number of such sets, it would be impractical to have to do a search-and-replace for every .txt file.

Is there a way for matlab to read the data as it appears, as in the above example (with the space preceding 'E'), and put it into a column vector?

For anyone who knows PARI-GP, an alternate fix would be to have the output devoid of spaces in the first place--but so far I haven't found a way to erase the space before 'E' in scientific notation, and I can't predict if a number in scientific notation will appear or not in the data set.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, I have found a solution. There is a way to eliminate the space from PARI-GP, so that the output .txt file has no spaces to begin with. I had the output set to "prettymatrix". One needs to enter the following:

```
    ? \o{0}
```

to change the output to "Raw," which eliminates the space before the "E" in scientific notation.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way, may not be the best, is to read line by line, remove the space and convert back to floating point number.

For example,

```
x = []
tline = fgetl(FileID);
while ischar(tline)
    x = [x str2num(tline(find(~isspace(tline))))]
    tline = fgetl(FileID);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the timely response!

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
data = str2double(strsplit(strrep(fileread('filename.txt'),' ',''), '\n'));
```

`strrep` removes all the spaces, `strsplit` takes each line as a separate string, and `str2double` coverts the strings to numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am currently trying your fix.

Comment: I'm sure it would have worked, and it seemed to be working, if the file I was applying this to were smaller--it had a billion lines!